# Nativescript 8 not syncing the app upon update

Tags: nativescript, nativescript-angular

I just migrated my previously build angular app to NS 8 and when I do 'ns run android' or ns debug android' it builds it the first time and installs it on my simulator. However, it doesn't activate it. I have to activate it myself. And from then on it doesn't do any update. If I make file changes, I see it update, but it doesn't seem to sync it over to the simulator.

```
webpack 5.31.2 compiled successfully in 17799 ms
Webpack compilation complete. Watching for file changes.
```

How do I get live syncing to work with NS8?

Comment: You don't, its buggy that way, sometimes it updates sometimes it dont. On ios it always updates for some reason so I relay on that. And on type of change, is it core change, js or style it acts different.. Also sometimes killing the terminal and running `tns run xx` shows the changes, sometimes you need to do `tns run xx --clean` For now I would suggest getting use to this workflow.

Comment: That's ridiculous. It takes so long to develop for nativescript if you have to stop, start and recompile for every update.

Comment: Dont get me wrong im new too it. But i think im right. I have seen some talk about it in dev support on discord, so devs are aware of this problemt. Also it does work sometimes, on adndroid. But like i said i relay on ios mostly, and just check / adapt new features for android on android. But it is time consuming, in both cases, i guess it is what it it is.

Comment: I’m not new to it. I’ve been developing for several years. It’s always worked right until around v7

Comment: Oh i didnt know that, good info. I got into it few days before NS8, then switched to it and started building. So i guess I just took what was offered without knowing hot it worked  before.